# Потоки, join, synchronized

Tags: java, многопоточность

Уже совсем запутался с `synchronized` и `join` методами.
Есть пример:

```
class Callme {
    void call(String msg) {
        System.out.print("[" + msg);
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Interrupted");
        }
        System.out.println("]");
    }
}

class Caller implements Runnable {
    String msg;
    Callme target;
    Thread t;

    public Caller(Callme targ, String s) {
        target = targ;
        msg = s;
        t = new Thread(this);
        t.start();
    }

    // синхронизированные вызовы call()
    public void run() {
        synchronized (target) {
            // синхронизированный блок
            target.call(msg);
        }
    }
}

class Synchl {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Callme target = new Callme();
        Caller obi = new Caller(target, "welcome");
        Caller ob2 = new Caller(target, "synchronized");
        Caller ob3 = new Caller(target, "world");
    }
}
```

Как я понял, т.к. метод у нас синхронизированный, сначала обработается поток `obi` → `ob2` → `ob3`, т.е. будет последовательность сообщения

```
welcome
synchronized
world
```

Но вывод абсолютно рандомный.

Чтобы выводилось правильно нужно еще добавить:

```
try {
    obi.t.join();
    ob2.t.join();
    ob3.t.join();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    System.out.println("Прервано");
}
```

И вот тут я не понимаю почему? Разве `synchronized` блока не должно хватать?